Are these two radically different kinds of psychological concepts one representing behavior (to mean) and the other cognitive (to understand)?
We could say that ChatGTP does not understand what it is saying, or anything whatsoever,but we can say it still means what it says. So "to mean" is not a same kind of a cognitive concept than to understand or hearing or seeing. Following late Wittgenstein "to mean" more or less seems to represent behavior. So we seem to have at least two kinds of psychological concepts behavioral and cognitive?

In the Sender-Receiver model the Sender S encodes meaning into signs, such as the letters and words in this sentence, and the Receiver R observes the signs and then decodes the meaning. S (encode) --> signs --> R (decode).  ChatGPT does not have any psychology as sender or receiver. If the Receiver decodes the same meaning as the Sender intends when encoding the message then we refer to that as understanding the intended meaning. Senders and Receivers cannot read minds but we engage in mind reading efforts.

In semantics, there are two broad views: internalism and externalism. Externalism is the view that meaning bearers cause meaning, that is, meaning is a property of words, whereas on the internalist reading, it meaning is attributed to words by an agent. The simple dictionary definitions of the word "meaning" and "understanding" reflect that difference. We can simply avoid any conflict by broadening our phraseology to reflect which distinction we are making. "Conventional meaning" can be understood as an intersubjective and therefore external notion of meaning, and "personal meaning" is identifying that the meaning in question is subjective and constructed by the individual. When "personal meaning" is asserted against the "conventional meaning" of signs, we describe that as "idiosyncratic".
LLMs do not "understand" the text they create in the sense that they use the grammar of words, because they deal in small tokens that might even include spaces across boundaries of words. They also have no rules encoded for formal grammars: no way to parse adjectives, nouns, objects, or adjuncts. They take a very mathematical approach to building up associations between non-morphemic tokens into vector databases, for instance. However, the corpora that they analyze do have meaning because they are taken from samples that have conventional meaning. They simply perform measures of central tendency and reflect such meaning. Obviously, because there are outliers and the mathematics isn't aware of the semantics of the text, they produce hallucinations.
As for meaning through action, you are simply recognizing what J.L. Austin did many years ago in his distinction between locution, illocution, and perlocution. Obviously, LLMs don't mean anything because they have no capacity to manifest intention in their language use, at least not in the sense we use intention with people and language use. I personally take such intention that to equate the Wittgensteinian Sprachspiel which is a manifestation of a generalized notion of intelligence with wants, desires, beliefs, etc. Now we are in a position to answer your question:
You ask:

Are these two radically different kinds of psychological concepts one representing behavior (to mean) and the other cognitive (to understand)?

No. Simply put behavior is just the physical manifestation of the cognitive. Understanding the import of someone's behavior are both aspects of what Dennett called the intentional stance. From WP:

The intentional stance is a term coined by philosopher Daniel Dennett for the level of abstraction in which we view the behavior of an entity in terms of mental properties.

When we look to behavior to infer mental state, we are constructing meaning by associating behaviors, which are physical observables, to build up a picture of what is going on "inside" the head of the intentional agent. Of course, this is a different kind of internalism and externalism than that outlined above, because this is not concerned with language as meaning bearers, but rather behavior as signals of intention.
So, your question conflates two definitions of meaning. One sense of meaning is about the senses of symbols what we can take as "carrying meaning" or in Austin's language locutions. And the other has to do with "illoctionary and perlocutionary forces" (complementary forces), that is behaviors to communicate and respond to behaviors. LLMs deal only with constructing locutions, where as agents, who are said to possess the intentional stance also are capable of the later.

Very informative answer. However,  In my point of view if something is a common use of words meaning, then it is a right use. It is common to say that LLM's mean this or that. What is behind of surface "to mean" is in my point of view sometimes a dead end, because eventually we could start to speak about brains, atoms that make the brains  etc and eventually about particles that we don't know if they even exists, like strings.

If you compress psychology into one single sentence for the beginner:

Psychology is the study of human Affects, Behaviour and Cognition,
abbreviated “ABC”.

IMO it does not bring much clarity to relate this simple definition of psychology to the philosophy of the late Wittgenstein.
And to ask what ChatGPT means by its answers presupposes a definition of “meaning” when applied to non-human smart systems. This could be the subject of a separate question.

There are relevant views of psychology like behaviorism with respect to my question.
